# PHP REST client API call

Tags: php, json, api, rest, curl

I'm wondering, is there an easy way to perform a REST API GET call? I've been reading about cURL, but is that a good way to do it?

I also came across php://input but I have no idea how to use it. Does anyone have an example for me?

I don't need advanced API client stuff, I just need to perform a GET call to a certain URL to get some JSON data that will be parsed by the client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents` if the fopen wrappers are enabled. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

If they are not, and you cannot fix that because your host doesn't allow it, `cURL` is a good method to use.

Comment: Which method do you prefer and why: cURL or file_get_contents?

Comment: `file_get_contents` is generally easier, but can only handle `GET`. This seems to be enough for your case. I'd try that if you are 1. sure your server can handle it, and 2. you're sure that later on you don't need `POST`

Comment: file_get_contents seems to be the easiest for this use case.

Comment: cURL is really sketchy when you are trying to connect to a site with SSL.There is are several things that have to be just right which makes it delicate and a future problem you have to learn a second time to fix.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways to make REST client API call:

1. Use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

CURL is the simplest and good way to go. Here is a simple call

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POST DATA);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

2. Use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/)

It's a "PHP HTTP client that makes it easy to work with HTTP/1.1 and takes the pain out of consuming web services". Working with Guzzle is much easier than working with cURL.

Here's an example from the Web site:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();           // 200
echo $res->getHeader('content-type'); // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();                 // {"type":"User"...'
var_export($res->json());             // Outputs the JSON decoded data
```

3. Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

If you have a url and your php supports it, you could just call file_get_contents:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/api/call?param1=5');
```

if $response is JSON, use json_decode to turn it into php array:

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

4. Use [Symfony's RestClient](https://github.com/CircleOfNice/CiRestClientBundle)

If you are using Symfony there's a great rest client bundle that even includes all of the ~100 exceptions and throws them instead of returning some meaningless error code + message.

```
try {
    $restClient = new RestClient();
    $response   = $restClient->get('http://www.someUrl.com');
    $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
    $content    = $response->getContent();
} catch(OperationTimedOutException $e) {
    // do something
}
```

5. Use [HTTPFUL](http://phphttpclient.com/)

Httpful is a simple, chainable, readable PHP library intended to make speaking HTTP sane. It lets the developer focus on interacting with APIs instead of sifting through curl set_opt pages and is an ideal PHP REST client.

Httpful includes...

- Readable HTTP Method Support (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, and OPTIONS)
- Custom Headers
- Automatic "Smart" Parsing
- Automatic Payload Serialization
- Basic Auth
- Client Side Certificate Auth
- Request "Templates"

Ex.

**Send off a GET request. Get automatically parsed JSON response.**

The library notices the JSON Content-Type in the response and automatically parses the response into a native PHP object.

```
$uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%7B%22type%22:%22/music/artist%22%2C%22name%22:%22The%20Dead%20Weather%22%2C%22album%22:%5B%5D%7D";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($uri)->send();

echo 'The Dead Weather has ' . count($response->body->result->album) . " albums.\n";
```

Comment: This answer is really informative and explores a full range of options for readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$result = file_get_contents( $url );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php